Debian switches laptop speakers to headphones, but not HDMI to headphones, can audio output be autoswitched?
When using laptop speakers, plugging-in headphones autoswitches output from speakers to headphone, and vice-versa for unplugging. When using monitor's speakers over HDMI, there's no autoswitch:
Can audio output be autoswitched between devices when headphones are (un)plugged?
Debian 12 (bookworm), kernel version 6.7.9-2, pipewire 1.0.5.
Notes: pipewire-pulse supports module-switch-on-connect (which can be loaded via pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect), but not module-switch-on-port-available — alternative support is provided by session manager (source: freedesktop.org). The session manager is presumably pw-cli, but pw-cli load-module module-switch-on-port-available outputs Error: "Could not load module".

Audio autoswitching between laptop speakers and analog headphones is between different outputs of a single audio chip. The chip can even have some hardware support for it: with HD-Audio-style front panel audio jacks, it is a switchable feature within the sound chip that when enabled, automatically mutes other outputs when it detects headphones are plugged in.
(If you use e.g. alsamixer and select the actual hardware mixer of your sound chip instead of the simplified volume control provided by Pipewire, you might see it as the Auto-Mute toggle.)
With older AC97-style front panel audio jacks, it is actually a mechanical switch within the audio jack itself, which will interrupt the output signals to the speaker/line output when a headphone jack is plugged in.
When switching between HDMI and headphones of any type, or between laptop speakers and a USB headset, the audio data stream needs to be switched to a different audio chip. Pipewire can do that, but it will do it only if the output sink priorities are set correctly and automatic switching is enabled.
See this blog entry: it describes how to check and adjust audio sink priorities in wireplumber 0.4 series, which is what Debian 12 has. This advice will not be directly applicable if you have wireplumber 0.5 or greater, as the configuration method has changed in version 0.5.
In a nutshell: the first step is to enable automatic switching when a new sound device is plugged in. You can do that temporarily by running pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect.
This AskUbuntu.SE question also includes the suggestion to run pactl load-module module-switch-on-port-available: I understand that enables switching when a new port becomes available on an existing audio device.
To make the above commands persistent, read /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf for examples, and add the relevant part to a *.conf file in your ~/.config/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf.d/ directory (create it if it does not exist). For example:
pulse.cmd = [
    { cmd = "load-module" args = "module-always-sink" flags = [ ] } #default
    { cmd = "load-module" args = "module-switch-on-connect" } #uncommented
    { cmd = "load-module" args = "module-switch-on-port-available" }  #added
    #{ cmd = "load-module" args = "module-gsettings" flags = [ "nofail" ] }
]

The second step is to ensure your sound devices are getting appropriate priorities assigned to them.
You can use wpctl status to see the identification numbers for any devices Pipewire cares about, then wpctl inspect <number> | grep -e node -e priority to see the name(s), description and priority of a particular audio device. If the default priority order is not the one you want, you can create a ~/.config/wireplumber/main.lua.d/60-*.lua file to adjust them, with contents similar to this:
rule = {
  matches = {
    {
      { "node.name", "equals", "alsa_output.usb-MOTU_M4_M4MC0570FU-00.Direct__hw_M4__sink" },
    },
  },
  apply_properties = {
    ["priority.driver"] = 1050,
    ["priority.session"] = 1050,
  },
}

The default priority for the "expected" primary sound device should be about 1009, so by assigning a higher value to some other sound device would make pipewire prefer it over others if it is available. But you should not assign a value higher than 1500, because the values higher than that are reserved for monitor devices.
There apparently are priority values for individual ports too, unfortunately I don't currently know how to customize them. You can view them with pactl list cards although the output is pretty long.
If someone knows a good way to adjust Pipewire port priorities, feel free to edit it if you don't want to write a complete answer of your own.

pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect didn't help, for pactl load-module module-switch-on-port-available I got Failure: No such entity. (Priorities are correct, headphone/laptop speaker has highest.)

pipewire-pulse supports some pulseaudio modules (including module-switch-on-connect), but not module-switch-on-port-available, which explains the above failure. Rather than temporarily supporting those modules, I made the above change to /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf and rebooted (I believe systemctl --user restart pipewire.service suffices). Unfortunately that didn't help: Audio still isn't autoswitching.
